# Trying to configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable but my .bash_profile has >>> conda initialize >>> in it

Tags: bash, react-native, anaconda, development-environment

I am trying to set up my Android Development Environment for React-Native and I am following this guide for MacOS.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

However, when I try to go to configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable in my .bash_profile file, it already has a bunch of stuff in it. It looks like it's from anaconda3. I am not sure if I should delete this code because this is supposed to be a read-only file. Has anyone encountered this before?

```
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

[attached is a picture of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP9IH.png)

Comment: If you want to know if `conda initialize` is setting those variables (which I personally doubt), run `set -x` to enable tracing and `set +x` to disable it. If you want the trace to include file names and line numbers, put `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$BASH_LINENO+'` in your file before the `set -x`.

Comment: And logs should be included _as text_ in the question itself, not as screenshot attachments. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: (BTW, any script using `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` is written by amateurs -- that practice causes bugs, especially when an ERR trap or `set -e` is enabled; the better way to write it would be `if __conda_setup=$(...); then`, with no need to check `$?`).

Comment: BTW, just because that block of your file is listed as managed by a separate program doesn't mean you can't add your own code before or after that block. Making `.bash_profile` be in entirety managed or read-only would be... very bad practice; it's _intended_ to be available as a place where users can configure their own environment.